# What is the best way to store integers with void pointers in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack, void-pointers

Hello i am trying to learn and build data structures in c and i want to store integers progressively in the stack.
my struct is like this:

```
typedef struct STACK_NODE_s *STACK_NODE;
typedef struct STACK_NODE_s{
    STACK_NODE forward;
    void *storage;
} STACK_NODE_t;

typedef struct L_STACK_s{
    STACK_NODE top;
} L_STACK_t, *L_STACK;
```

In a while loop i want to read and store my chars in integer form.

```
//assume that str is an proper string
//assume that we have a linked stack called LS
int i=0;
int temp;
while(str[i]!='\0'){
    tmp=str[i]-'0';
    push(LS,(void *)&tmp);
}
```

I know this won't work properly as we store the same variable's adress over and over again.
Do i need to allocate an auxiliary array in order to store them 1 by 1 or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the reason your stack uses `void*` for storing data?

Comment: For a generic library-like  implementation.

Comment: In that case you will have to use `malloc` (or dynamically allocate the data in some other way that outlives the stack) and remember to `free` all elements when destroying the stack

Comment: @UnholySheep Hmm i am getting used to these adresses and they still confuse me a bit. I will try that approach thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer must address two separate aspects of your question:
How to organize some collection of items, and where to get the memory from to do that.

#### First code snippet / Linked list format

The first code snippet is good the way it is.
It sets up a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), which has its pros and cons, but serves very well if you don't know the number of items in advance, if you want to be able to quickly remove or insert items somewhere in the middle of the list, and if you don't mind that looking up one certain entry inside the list costs you [**O(N)** effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_symbol).

> For a generic library-like implementation...

... `void*` is as good as it goes with ANSI C.
In C++, for example, you could make a template that leaves open the type that is stored in the list (or better yet, you would directly reuse the well-known STL implementation in class `forward_list<int>`).
Sadly, ANSI C doesn't have something comparable.
One solution is the one you picked, create `int` objects and hook their addresses into your list of `void*`.
Another solution for a generic library implementation is to use a precompiler macro for the type, and to define this macro above a header file that holds the generic implementation. This tries to resemble the clean C++ solution, but with precompiler it is not typesafe, so this approach is far from beautiful and comes with several risks.

#### Second code snippet / Memory allocation

Creating the list with `void*` instead of `int` (or whatever non-pointer type) requires you to allocate further memory beside the list. 
I. e., it is not only that you have to allocate every list item (= variable of type `STACK_NODE_t`) but also the actual entry value (e. g., `*(int*)(LS->storage)`).

This means you have to allocate/deallocate the data in some other way that outlives the stack.
On most systems, you can use `malloc`/`free` for that, and you only have to take into account the size of the heap available for `malloc` and the time de-/allocating takes.
If the list shall implement real-time requirements or on embedded systems, you may not have `malloc` or you may not be allowed to use it.
Then you have to allocate and implement your own heap (= memory pool of `storage` items) for your list.
How to implement such a memory pool with desired properties is a separate question that would take us to far here.

In any case, you must not use the pointer to a stack variable (like a local variable inside a function) because the memory "behind" that variable will not be reserved for this purpose once the function exits, and the memory may be used for something different in the meantime.
This is, however, what the second code snippet does apparently.
As you noticed yourself, taking this path...

> we store the same variable's adress over and over again.

Reusing the memory position for another entry of the same list is an extreme case of the risk explained above.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed explaining and great help. I learned many new things about malloc and unused memory management thanks to this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using an auxiliary array like i anticipated. If someone comes up with a better solution its more than welcome.

Comment: Why you didn't put the address of str[i] directly convert it to an integer then take the address of it and push it into the stack?